# Encontrar o valor agrupado por menor ocorrência da data

Tags: sql, query, group-by

Como faria uma consulta, para ter, O código do cliente a primeira data que ele aparece na tabela e o valor dela?

```
| codCliente | MIN(dtRef) AS MenorData | Net AS Valor | 


insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (3148597  , '2021-07-16' , 2222.00  );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (3694254  , '2021-07-16' , 150031.50);
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (2667177  , '2021-07-16' , 5823.44  );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (4298109  , '2021-07-16' , 511.31   );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (2302783  , '2021-07-16' , 17650.00 );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (2953299  , '2021-07-16' , 50744.88 );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (4298109  , '2021-09-16' , 511.31   );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (2302783  , '2021-09-16' , 17650.00 );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (2953299  , '2021-05-16' , 50744.88 );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (3469649  , '2021-04-16' , 11027.67 );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (32953    , '2021-03-16' , 30045.00 );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (2667177  , '2021-02-16' , 22518.00 );
insert into tb_dados (codCliente, dtRef, Net ) Values (2088752  , '2021-07-15' , 5501.90  );
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira simples de resolver o problema é fixando o valor da menor data, e comparando com a tabela agregando os valores por data e código do cliente tendo o codcliente como condição de junção.

Um exemplo desta implementação seria:

```
SELECT a.dtRef, a.codcliente, a.Net FROM tb_dados a, tb_dados b
WHERE a.codcliente = b.codcliente
GROUP BY a.codcliente, a.dtRef
HAVING a.dtref = MIN(b.dtref);
```

Fiz desta forma para ser mais didático.

É possível ré-escrever esta consulta para utilizar o `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.dtRef, a.codcliente, a.Net FROM tb_dados a
INNER JOIN tb_dados b ON a.codcliente = b.codcliente
GROUP BY a.codcliente, a.dtRef
HAVING a.dtref = MIN(b.dtref);
```

A cláusula `INNER JOIN` atua em conjuntos (que no modelo relacional são tabelas) através da intersecção entre os elementos do conjunto.
No nosso caso a intersecção está representada na cláusula `ON`

### Porque utilizar a cláusula HAVING?

A cláusula having deve ser utilizada quando queremos aplicar alguma condição no conjunto agregado de dados (após a execução da cláusula `group by`). [`Ref`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj14854.html)

Uma definição da [`Wikipedia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL)) em uma tradução livre:

> WHERE é avaliado em um estágio anterior da execução de uma consulta, filtrando as linhas lidas das tabelas. Se uma consulta contiver GROUP BY, as linhas das tabelas serão agrupadas e agregadas. Após a operação de agregação, HAVING é aplicado, filtrando as linhas que não correspondem às condições especificadas. Portanto, WHERE se aplica a dados lidos de tabelas e HAVING deve se aplicar apenas a dados agregados, que não são conhecidos no estágio inicial de uma consulta.

### Resultados equivalentes utilizando uma sub-consulta

```
SELECT a.dtRef, a.codcliente, a.Net FROM tb_dados AS a
WHERE a.dtRef = (
  SELECT MIN(dtRef) FROM tb_dados 
  WHERE codCliente = a.codCliente
);
```

Aqui vamos utilizar uma sub-consulta para encontrar o menor valor da coluna data para um cliente específico e depois filtrar os resultados de acordo com a menor data.

Comment: perfeito.. era isso que precisava.. muito obrigado ...

Answer (score -4):

No meu código coloquei para ordenar o select por data e limitar o resultado a 1 registro.

```
SELECT dtRef, codcliente, Net
  FROM tb_dados
  where codcliente = 2953299
  order by dtRef asc
  limit 1;
```

Você pode ver melhor meu código e fazer seus próprios testes no link: https://sqltest.net/#1606067

Answer (score -4):

ola, tudo certo? Acho que o que voce precisa é:

SELECT codCliente, min(dtRef), Net
FROM tb_dados
GROUP BY codCliente, Net

o método min() é um agrupador de dados, portanto, se no SELECT houverem mais colunas, deve-se informa-las no GROUP BY.