# Trazer último registro de cada ID diferente - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

TABELA 'STATUS DAS PROPOSTAS'

```
ID        | DATA DE ATUALIZAÇÃO | STATUS
123456789 | 2022-01-01          | 5
123456789 | 2022-01-02          | 6
123456789 | 2022-01-07          | 8
658945491 | 2022-02-06          | 1
658945491 | 2022-02-07          | 10
658945491 | 2022-02-08          | 15
222222222 | 2022-02-28          | 5
222222222 | 2022-03-01          | 6
222222222 | 2022-03-02          | 8
```

Quero o último registro de cada uma das propostas, logo a query precisa retornar as seguintes informações:

```
ID        | DATA DE ATUALIZAÇÃO | STATUS
123456789 | 2022-01-07          | 8
658945491 | 2022-02-08          | 15
222222222 | 2022-03-02          | 8
```

Tentei `select distinct id, max('DATA DE ATUALIZAÇÃO'), STATUS' FROM 'STATUS DAS PROPOSTAS'`, mas retorna apenas a data de atualização máxima e não traz o último status.

Comment: Uma vez eu respondi uma pergunta parecida. [veja se ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/541923/103217)

Answer (score -2):

Há uma propriedade interessante chamada ROW_NUMBER() para resolver esse tipo de caso, mas infelizmente não está disponível para MySQL.

Veja a consulta:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.data_de_atualizacao,
    t1.status
FROM tabela t1
   INNER JOIN
   (
       SELECT 
              id, 
              max(data_de_atualizacao) ult_data_de_atualizacao
         FROM tabela
     GROUP BY id
   ) t2 ON 
   t1.id = t2.id 
   AND
   t1.data_de_atualizacao = t2.ult_data_de_atualizacao
```